Entropy and the cyclic universe
Does Tolman’s entropy problem apply to Roger Penrose’s conformal cyclic cosmology or Steinhardt’s cyclic model?

How is this "needs details or clarity"? Tolman's argument about increasing entropy in a cyclic universe will be well know to anyone who has studied cosmology, and Penrose's idea should be equally well know to anyone who reads the popular science press. The question is asking how Penrose's proposed mechanism avoids the problem of monotonically increasing entropy.

I don't know a lot about Penrose's idea but I believe he related entropy to the Weyl curvature, and in CCC the Weyl curvature approaches zero at each transition between cycles so each cycle automatically starts in a low entropy state. If by Steinhart's model you mean brane cosmology then it isn't a cyclic universe - just a periodic change in a submanifold of a higher dimensional non-oscillating universe.
